# How to get IP addresses of computers using BroadcastAddress in Android

Tags: android, broadcast

In my application I'd like to get all the IP addresses that are taken by computers in the LAN using the broadcast address. I used the following code to determine the broadcast address.

```
InetAddress getBroadcastAddress()
  {
    try
    {
      WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      DhcpInfo dhcp = wifi.getDhcpInfo();
      // handle null somehow

      int broadcast = (dhcp.ipAddress & dhcp.netmask) | ~dhcp.netmask;
      byte[] quads = new byte[4];
      for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        quads[k] = (byte) ((broadcast >> k * 8) & 0xFF);
      return InetAddress.getByAddress(quads);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Now that I have it, as far as I know, when one uses the broadcast address, every computer answers it, so if I simply send a "ping" message to that address, the computers of the LAN will answer it. How should I ping them in Android? What command would send me the taken addresses?

The following code simply returns the packet from the sending phone but I need the computers' addresses:

```
 int PORT = 8080;
 int DISCOVERY_PORT = 8080;
 try
 {
  DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
  socket.setBroadcast(true);
  String data="TEST";
  DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data.getBytes(), data.length(),
  getBroadcastAddress(), DISCOVERY_PORT);
  socket.send(packet);

  byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
  DatagramPacket packet2 = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
  Log.w(Tags.DEBUG,"Receive start");
  socket.receive(packet2);
  Log.w(Tags.DEBUG,packet2.getAddress().toString());
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Is it even possible?

EDIT:

If I'm honest it works as it is written: my phone sends an UDP packet and my phone receives the incoming packages. As the only package is coming from my phone, it is obvious that the address is my phone's address. However, if the broadcast address is valid, each network interface should send the signal back. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are partially correct.

When you send a UDP packet to a broadcast address, all the computers on the network will receive the packet, unless a router on the network restricts UDP packets being sent to the broadcast address. This is mostly the case on a corporate network.

But not all computers will reply to that packet, they need to know what to do with it.

- Either you write a server application that understands your UDP packet and is configured to reply to that packet and deploy that server application to all of the computers on the network.
- Or you implement an existing discovery protocol such as Bonjour (Mac) or SSDP (Windows)

I suggest you take a look at ZeroConf Service Discovery if you want to use existing protocols rather then deploying your own application.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking#Service_discovery

I hope this explanation helps you with your problem.

Comment: Yes, it does. I already started implementing the first way (UDP server application).

Comment: @Nestor I need some thing like this. Can you share some info about it?

Comment: @learner You can see the Android client in the initial post. I created a .Net UDP listener service (UDP server application) and when it receives the UDP packet then sends a response packet to the client. The server applications is like this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92846ccb-fad3-469a-baf7-bb153ce2d82b/simple-udp-example-code?forum=netfxnetcom